# What is the exact use of semver notation in package.json file?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I want to know the exact difference between the **semver notations** in package.json. Can someone explain me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the npm documentation explains it well: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/semver#advanced-range-syntax

Since there is a lot going on, perhaps a brief explanation of the two most common:

The caret modifier (^) will automatically go the highest minor and patch version, **unless** the major version is 0. In this case, will only update the patch version.

The tilde modifier (~) will only go to the highest patch version. So ~ and ^ are equal when the major version is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Semver notation isn't specifically `used` in `package.json`.

If it's followed (*1), it helps developers to understand what to expect from any particular update. Imagine you want to bump the version of a library, and you see that the difference is in the `major` part of the version (n in `n.*.*`). This can point out to potential repercussions of upgrading the package - according to SEMVER `MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,`.

*1 It's not always followed by developers. One prominent example is React Native. The developers have never released a Major version, and treat `MINOR` as `MAJOR`

Comment: The way it is done with React Natve is actual compliant with semantic versioning. When the major version is 0 every update in minor version supposed to be treated as though it is an update in major version. This is also reflected by the ^ notation.

Answer (score 0):

I got this from node js documentation. There is a pretty well explanation for question.

https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-package-lock-json-file

In package.json you can set which versions you want to upgrade to (patch or minor), using the semver notation, for example:

- if you write ~0.13.0, you want to only update patch releases: 0.13.1
  is ok, but 0.14.0 is not.
- if you write ^0.13.0, you want to get
  updates that do not change the leftmost non-zero number: 0.13.1,
  0.13.2 and so on.
- If you write ^1.13.0, you will get patch and minor releases: 1.13.1, 1.14.0 and so on up to 2.0.0 but not 2.0.0.
- if you
  write 0.13.0, that is the exact version that will be used, always